# ASP.Net LoadComplete event running before Page Load?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to calculate the current offset from UTC time when a page is loaded. This I can do very simply via a javascript function call as part of the page's body onload event as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function getOffset() {
        var curUTCDate = new Date();
        var iMins = curUTCDate.getTimezoneOffset();
        return iMins;
    }
</script>

<body id="bodymain" onload="javascript:document.forms[0]['hdnOffset'].value=getOffset();">
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <input id="hdnOffset" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

However when I try to use this value in the code behind as part of Page_LoadComplete on the server side the offset value has not been set as shown below

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnOffset.Value))
        {
            lblText.Text = hdnOffset.Value + " value set";
        }
        else
        {
            lblText.Text = " value not set ";
        }
    }
```

however the offset does become available once the Page has fully rendered as its value is now displayed in the input box. So to me this looks as if the javascript called as part of a body onload event only gets called after the Page has completely loaded.

How is this even possible?

Comment: Because the body onload event occurs on the client side after the page has been fully rendered from the server.  The only event that occurs on the server at this point is `Unload`.  If you're expecting client-to-server communication without a postback, you'll need to use ajax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're confusing two completely different "load" events here.

First, the server side code (in your case ASP.NET) runs *in its entirety*. In this cycle, there are a couple of things that happen, and among them are the `Load` and `LoadComplete` events.

When the server is done determining *what should be rendered*, it starts sending stuff (HTML and JavaScript, usually) to the browser. On the browser end, **another** `load` event is triggered - that of the `<body>` element on the page. They're named the same, but they're completely independent.

To fix this problem, set `lblText.Text` to `"value not set"` on the server side, and change it in JavaScript when you change the offset indicator.

Server side:

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Possibly even better to do this in the properties of the control...
    lblText.Text = "value not set...";
}
```

Client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function setOffset() {
        var curUTCDate = new Date();
        var iMins = curUTCDate.getTimezoneOffset();
        document.forms[0]['hdnOffset'].value = iMins;
        document.getElementById('lblText').innerHtml = 'value set';
    }
</script>

<body id="bodymain" onload="javascript:setOffset();">
```

If you're not using ASP.NET 4, where you are given extensive control over the client-side IDs of your controls, you should take a look at jQuery. It's a javascript library that you can use for an endless amount of things, which will in this specific case make it a lot easier to find the label control.

Comment: thanks, very good explanation. Unfortunately jQuery won't work in this case since I need to use the offset for a variety of different server side methods. Think I'll just put in a background worker to check when the value becomes available & use it from there on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.Net will have finished processing the page before it returns the HTML to the browser at which point the onload function is called.

Comment: I can understand that however even if I carry out the check at SaveStateComplete the value is not available. Since the SavedStateComplete event is pretty much the last event used, with the exception of Unload this means that all the asp.net lifecycle events occur before any client side load events. Is this expected behaviour ??

Comment: All the ASP.Net lifecycle events complete and the page is then rendered and sent to the client. Once the page is received by the browser and loaded, the javascript methods fire.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following link to read about Page life cycle ..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx