# How to run JavaScript code before page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have working in **asp.net** web application. Here I need to run **JavaScript** before page load.

I have tried:

```
<body oninit="funinit();" onprerender="funRender();" onload="funload();">


</body>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function funinit() {
        alert("funinit");
    }
    function funload() {
        alert("funload");
    }
    function funRender() {
        alert("funRender");
    }      

</script>
```

here only funload() is working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666037/asp-net-loadcomplete-event-running-before-page-load

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use window.onpaint for such purpose like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preloadFunc()
    {
        alert("PreLoad");
    }
    window.onpaint = preloadFunc();
</script>
```

I hope it helps you....

Comment: FYI: `onpaint doesn't work currently, and it is questionable whether this event is going to work at all`, more at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23657265/216084

Comment: According to [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onpaint), not only onpaint is non-standard and doesn't work on Firefox (so it wouldn't be a good cross browser solution), but it also runs **after** the onload event

Comment: @user216084 your comment was 4 years after this anwser!

Answer (score 15):

Just inline it?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert("funload");
</script>
```

Or put it in a function and call it immediately. Try to put it to the topmost of your page, however since the DOM isnt loaded yet you cant get any other elements.

What is it you want to do?

Answer (score 10):

just insert a <script> tag wherever inside the body you want it to run. it will be executed as soon as the parser reads it, as long as it doesn't reference an element not yet created

Answer (score 7):

try to put your script in head section of the page:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        alert("funinit");
        alert("funRender");
  </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not Use the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx