# What is window.onpaint?

Tags: javascript

Someone recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944037/how-to-run-java-script-code-before-page-load) that `window.onpaint` be used to run some javascript before page load. I've never actually seen this before, could someone explain its usage/usefulness?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onpaint) :

> onpaint doesn't work currently, and it is questionable whether this
>   event is going to work at all, [see bug 239074](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=239074).

So the usefulness is zero.

It might depend on your exact use case but if you want to run a script "before page load", the simplest solution is probably to put it in the `head`.