# Modify HTML before Chrome native scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I modify the HTML page before any Chrome runs its scripts, or
make my script run before any source script, once Chrome gets the whole HTML plain text.

Can any Chrome API do that?

Comment: The browser runs script elements in the order they appear in the html - it has to, in case there are document.write() statements, or other things that affect the page. So you can't have an extension script that runs *after* the html is parsed but *before* any other JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944037/how-to-run-java-script-code-before-page-load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944037/how-to-run-java-script-code-before-page-load)

Comment: It can be done with a MutationObserver inside a content script that runs at document_start. There are many examples, including page element modification.